# Is it possible to NOT display the application name in a Grappelli-Dashboard module.AppList?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-grappelli

I am using Grappelli-Dashboard for my Django admin site. I would like to customize the display of the app headers so that the name of the app is NOT displayed. Is that possible? If so, how? I can't figure it out...?
Given the code below, I do NOT want the name of both apps displayed (i.e. I don't want the admin to show a header for 'Things' and a header for 'Items)

```
        self.children.append(modules.Group(
        _('MyStuff'),
        column=3,
        collapsible=True,
        children = [
            modules.AppList(
                _('Stuff Details'),
                column=1,
                collapsible=True,
                models=('things.models', ),
            ),
            modules.AppList(
                _('Stuff Data'),
                column=1,
                collapsible=True,
                models=('items.models.*', ),
            ),

        ]
    ))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to override the template files that generate the admin interface.  Find where the grapelli dashboard module is installed, look inside its templates directory, and find the template html file that you want to change.  Copy that template file into your own app's templates directory (making sure it has the same path structure within "templates") and edit your copy of it to remove the app name.